# 3.1 or 5.1 audio in Flash

Tags: flash, audio

Is it possible to do 3.1 or 5.1 audio using Flash?  We're starting a project here for an interactive kiosk, and we've been told to use Flash.  However, we also have a requirement to support either 3.1 or 5.1 audio (where 5.1 is the most wanted feature).

I haven't done any high-tech audio stuff using Flash, so I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search gave me this forum http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=715062 where they state that Flash is unable to handle 5.1 audio and the alternative is to use another application that can communicate with Flash to handle the audio side of things.

I also found this blog entry from Summit Projects http://summitprojectsflashblog.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/wave-theory-in-actionscript-3-part-4/ where they go into great detail about byte handling and processing audio samples. I'm not sure if they are using their own actionscript libraries for this, or if they are using Adobe's libraries. I'm not too up to speed on the audio side of Flash with respects to surround sound.

I think your two options might have to be either using a separate application to run your audio(which may be less stressful) or maybe getting in touch with the Summit people if you are as lost as I am over some of the concepts they touch on, heh. Good luck!

Comment: The Summit Projects link you posted only tells you about how to decode the audio data, it doesn't provide a means of communication with a computers audio hardware, which is the fundamental problem. This is why you have to use an external application for this purpose. Maybe we'll get some more advanced audio support with Molehill?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.

You **might** be able to do it if you use uncompressed wave files already encoded in DTS or something and put a surround receiver in between. This will however stop you from doing anything with the sound before outputting it, not even changing the volume. And I guess that's not an option?
I think going with an external application for sound would be your best choice, maybe you can do something using Director.

Answer (score 0):

With AIR 3 and Flash Player 11 it is possible.